# SolrInputDocument throwing MessageFormatException when added to ActiveMQ?

Tags: solr, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I'm trying to add a SolrInputDocment (which is Serializable) to an ActiveMQ queue (using a Camel producer template), but I get a MessageFormatException...any ideas?

here is my code...

```
SolrInputDocument doc1 = new SolrInputDocument();
doc1.addField( "id", "1234", 1.0f );

template.sendBody("activemq:queue:test", doc1);
```

here is my error...

```
Caused by: javax.jms.MessageFormatException: Only objectified primitive objects, String, Map and List types are allowed but was: id(1.0)={1234} type: class org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputField
```

UPDATE: the issue is that I need to explicitly set the JMSMessageType to 'Object', otherwise the MapMessage is used (which doesn't support custom types)...

```
template.sendBodyAndHeader("activemq:queue:test", doc1, JMS_MESSAGE_TYPE, "Object");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115971/bind-a-custom-object-to-a-jms-mapmessage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your message properties contain some complex java Object, how about if you try to send a "clean" SolrInputDocument?

Cheers,Eugene.

Comment: thanks, w/o the addField() call, it does work...strange that calling addField() (which creates a LinkedHashMap<String,SolrInputField> all of which are Serializable) breaks it...

Comment: @boday what I did is look into the sources of where this Exception is thrown, and there I saw that it has to do with message PROPERTIES and not the body, so that was my first hint to look. So Serializable I think has nothing to do with it. Anyhow if it helped I would appreciated and extra 15 on my account :) Thx!

Comment: thanks for your input...but I'm not explicitly setting any properties...hence my confusion.  this works fine w/o calling addField() (which only affects the body)...also, I tried with another POJO object and it works fine as well...anyways, its a strange error

Comment: @boday weird indeed then. Is there a way you could add a Filter may be to catch this request to see how it looks like?

Comment: Camel must be causing this...I switched to using a JMSTemplate directly it worked fine...

Comment: @boday really glad you got it solved then. Seems like Camel is adding something behinds the scenes, might test it myself whenever I have a bit of free time. Cheers, Eugene.

Comment: @boday good to know for people in the future who will try the same thing. You actually deserve a +15 yourself :)