# javax.jms.MessageFormatException: Invalid message format

Tags: date, jms, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, message-queue

When I try to send `Date` object in `MapMessage` using JMS on Glassfish 3.1 Open MQ I get the following error:

```
javax.jms.MessageFormatException: [C4017]: Invalid message format.
```

Following is the code for how I am trying to send the `Date` object in `MapMessage`:

```
public class JSenderMockClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {           
            //using jndiContext to get ConnectionFactory, Queue, Session and stuff

            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);

            MapMessage mapMessage = session.createMapMessage();
            mapMessage.setObject("now", new Date());

            producer.send(mapMessage);

            System.out.println("MapMessage \"now\" sent..");            
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            //just in case stuff
        } finally {
            //closing session and connection
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone help me understand why am I getting this exception?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think MapMessage only support Strings and primitives. You could serialize the date to a string, or you could use an ObjectMessage.

To serialize the date, you could use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

See [bind a custom object to a JMS MapMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115971/bind-a-custom-object-to-a-jms-mapmessage)